# Bing Search API

Tags: java, jar, applet, bing-api

I am using Bing Search API to my applet application and I used this code:

```
byte[] accountKeyBytes = Base64.encodeBase64((accountKey + ":" + accountKey).getBytes());
String accountKeyEnc = new String(accountKeyBytes);
```

I used `commons-codec-1.7.jar` and does not recognized the `encodeBase64`.

I have try everything, I have place the jar file through the project directory through source file.

Comment: Are you using maven or something similar? Maybe there is a dependency conflict because some other library pulls in an older version of commons-codec?

Comment: I am using  Apache Commons Codec

Comment: Show the import statement. Maybe it's not using the correct Base64.

Comment: import java.util.Base64; this is the import statement which i used

Comment: 1) Always copy/paste error and exception output! 2) Describe the locations of the HTML and the Jar on the server.

Comment: Can you explain me because I dont understand what do yo u mean?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your import statement is the following:

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
```

Comment: when I used this statement cannot resolve symbol Base64

Comment: Have you added the commons-coded jar to the classpath?

Comment: yes I have added. The jar file is in the source directory. Is it okay?

Comment: How have you added it to the classpath? Just putting the jar in the source directory won't work.

Comment: Which IDE do you use?

Comment: Ok, I'm not familiar with Intellij, but have a look here on how to add jars: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1051640/correct-way-to-add-lib-jar-to-an-intellij-idea-project